# Restrict paths from syncing with server in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently evaluating Firebase. In my application I allow users to create entities (custom exercises) which are stored in SQLite DB now. I want to move this to FB, but I have a question.

I want to allow users to authenticate to be able to sync their exercises with other devices. Fairly standard use case. But I don't want to force users to have an account with my app, so they can use it anonymously as long as they want and don't need the sync. Is there a way to disable syncing with the server when they are anonymous? This makes no sense to sync anonymous data with server, because they won't be able to pick it up anyway, so, should they change a device or factory reset, they will get a new ID and that data will become abandoned.

So what I want is while a user is anonymous - to keep his stuff local only in Firebase RTDB, but, as soon as he logs in, sync it. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database, that continues to work for brief to intermediate moments where you are not connected to the network. If you're looking for a database that works for indefinitely periods of offline, with only a potential synchronization at some point, the Firebase Database might not be a good fit at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any chance this will be added in the future? What I want looks like a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use the database [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to achieve the desired behavior.

Set read to be global, while write is restricted to authenticated users only. When an anonymous user makes an account, the user therefore gains write access and all the local data can then be pushed onto the database.

Comment: But if a write is restricted to authenticated users, doesn't it mean, the user won't be able to write to a local FB storage as well? I thought rules applied to entire database, not just online part.

Comment: when you said "to keep his stuff local", what did you mean by local? I assumed locally on the device. Another way I suppose is to create auto-generated user-ids for all users, and "non-anonymous" users are simply users with custom user-ids that they set themselves

Comment: "local" is in the Firebase Realtime Database, but only locally. Without syncing them to a server.